# Pyspark make multiple files based on dataframe groupBy

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can group large datasets and make multiple CSV, excel files with Pandas data frame. But how to do the same with the Pyspark data frame to group **700K** records into around **230** groups and make **230** CSV files country wise.

**Using pandas**

```
grouped = df.groupby("country_code")

# run this to generate separate Excel files
for country_code, group in grouped:
    group.to_excel(excel_writer=f"{country_code}.xlsx", sheet_name=country_code, index=False)
```

**with Pyspark data frame**, when I try to like this-

```
for country_code, df_country in df.groupBy('country_code'):
    print(country_code,df_country.show(1))
```

It returns,

> TypeError: 'GroupedData' object is not iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your requirement is to save all country data in different files you can achieve it by partitioning the data but instead of file you will get folder for each country because spark can't save data to file directly.

Spark creates folder whenever a dataframe writer is called.

```
df.write.partitionBy('country_code').csv(path)
```

The output will be multiple folders with corresponding country's data

```
path/country_code=india/part-0000.csv
path/country_code=australia/part-0000.csv
```

If you want one file inside each folder you can repartition your data as

```
df.repartition('country_code').write.partitionBy('country_code').csv(path)
```

Comment: some of my column contains array data structure, showing error __AnalysisException: CSV data source does not support array<struct<id:string,type:string>> data type.;__ after using `df.repartition('country_code').write.partitionBy('country_code').csv('grouped_data/')
` I think I need to cast the array to string before partinionBy to csv

Comment: You can explode/flatten the array or save the data as json or parquet file

Answer (score 1):

Use `partitionBy` at the time of writing so that every partition is based on the column you specify (`country_code` in your case).

Here's [more](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/partitionby/) on this.